# How to seperate data of a row if the data have # in it and insert it to another table from that table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a project table here:

```
id  sector                         project
1   Agriculture#Business#Private   Test
```

and i want to separate the sector by # and insert it into another project_sector table here:

```
id     project_id       sector  
1          1            Agriculture
2          1            Business
3          1            Private
```

can you guide me the query to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `string_to_array` and `unnest`

```
select id, 
       unnest(string_to_array(sector, '#')) as sector,
       project
from project;
```

The output of this query can of course be joined to other tables. For readability I prefer to put this into a common table expression.

```
with normalized_projects as (
    select id, 
           unnest(string_to_array(sector, '#')) as sector,
           project
    from project
)
select p.id as project_Id, 
       row_number() over (partition by p.id order by sector) as new_sector_id,
       p.sector, 
       p.project, s.sector_id
from normalized_projects p
  join sector s on s.sector_name = p.sector;
```

You might also want to consider making that normalized structure a view so you don't have to repeat that query all over the places

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fc14/3

Comment: ok that works but cant i use that sectors to join the another table??

Comment: i want to join the project table to sector table using that sector after unnest at the same query.. can we do that??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY sector) as id,
       project_id, 
       sector 
 from (select id as project_id, 
              unnest(string_to_array(sector, '#')) as sector
         from project) as t;
```